# Is there even an automatic ban on meta?

Tags: support, post-ban, per-site-meta

Somewhere I heard the automatic question ban on Meta is set lower than on the main site. But looking at the profile of [this user on SR.SE](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/users/103/sam) it looks like there is absolutely no automatic ban on meta.

Is this intended behaviour?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of February 16<sup>th</sup> 2017, [question bans are enabled on all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291142/comprehensive-question-quality-blocks-now-enabled-everywhere)

---

Before that, only a few sites had an automatic question ban. As of February 2014, these were [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Note that the quality bans are *disabled* on all meta sites, regardless of whether the parent site has them enabled or not (with Meta Stack Exchange being the only exception).

So at the time of this question, there was no automatic question ban on Meta.SR nor on SR itself.

Bonus information: All sites, including their meta sites, have an automatic answer ban. You have to work really hard to trigger it.